# weibliche Form: Bäuerin vs. Tiefbauerin (etc.)

Tags: difference, etymology

Ein Bauer ist ganz allgemein gesprochen jemand, der von der Bewirtschaftung landwirtschaftlicher Nutzflächen lebt (danke [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landwirt)).
Ein weiblicher Bauer ist eine Bäuerin.

Es gibt zahlreiche Berufe im Baugewerbe mit dem Wortbestandteil -bauer:
Hoch-, Tief-, Straßen-, Brückenbau und sicher etliche mehr.

Jemand, der Gruben für Keller auskoffert, ist ein Tiefbauer.
Ein weiblicher Tiefbauer ist eine Tiefbauerin.

In keinem Fall ist ein weiblicher Tiefbauer eine Tiefbäuerin und das gleiche gilt für die anderen Bezeichnungen mit „-bauer“.

Wann und weshalb haben sich die weiblichen Formen auseinanderentwickelt?
Oder liegt hier ein Missverständnis meinerseits vor, und Bauer (Landwirt) hat etymologisch nichts mit bauen zu tun?

Comment: Nur eine Anmerkung am Rande: Auch "Bauer" und "-bauer" laufen grammatikalisch nicht gleichauf - siehe die Pluralformen: "Die Bauern" vs. "die Tiefbauer" etc.

Comment: (pingelig an) Nachdem Keller typischerweise zu Häusern gehören, und diese sich überwiegend über der Erdoberfläche befinden, handelt es sich eher um eine *Hochbauerin*, wenn nicht gar um eine *Erdarbeiterin*, wogegen Straßenbau zum Tiefbau gehört. (pingelig aus). Trotzdem eine gute Frage.

Comment: @guidot pingelig hin oder her, Erdarbeiten (auch für den Keller oder auch nur vorbereitend für die Bodenplatte bei Häusern ohne Keller) werden vom Tiefbauer ausgeführt.

Comment: Lustigerweise sogar Brücken, auch wenn sie hoch sind.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Das sind verschiedene Morpheme.  *Tiefbauer* ist eine *-er*-Agensableitung von *Tiefbau*: *[Tief+bau]+er*, *[[Tief+bau]+er]+in*.  *Bauer* dagegen ist, synchron gesehen, keine Ableitung, sondern unteilbar; vgl.  *Berg+bauer*, *Berg+bäuerin* (dagegen hypothetischer Montanberuf: **[Berg+bau]+er*, **[[Berg+bau]+er]+in*).

Comment: "hypothetisch" ist bei Bergbauer wichtig. Niemand würde das als Bergarbeiter verstehen.

Comment: Ich habe versucht, Beispiele zu finden, bei denen beide Interpretationen möglich sind... vielleicht _Gartenbauerin_ / _Gartenbäuerin_ ("Landschaftsgestalterin" vs. "Agraristin mit Garten").